# How does Celery discover new Nodes?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery, gunicorn

I'm running Celery and RabbitMQ Gunicorn in Docker.

My question is this:  I understand that Celery is designed for distributed processing. What I have see no docs on at all is, assuming that I have several machines/nodes on the same LAN, how do they discover each other?  Does RabbitMQ play a role?  Do celery instances somehow discover each other?  Is there a list of suitable hosts somewhere?  If so, how do I edit it?

Also, assuming I'm going to use only one node to handle the HTTP requests, do I still need to have gunicorn running on all nodes?  I ask this because in the gunicorn start command, it has a setting for the number of workers.  And, is this setting applicable only to that node, or as a max total for all connected nodes?

EDIT:
After the first answer, I started working on this.  It seems that I need some sort of networking setup, either swarm or bridging etc.  I should clarify that I'm using docker-compose to bring up the solution, and I see that a normal swarm setup doesn't work, and I have to use something slightly different if I go that route.

**To be clear:**  I need a way in which I can add celery workers on separate hosts and have them be able to communicate with the "main" host so that I can increase the capacity of the system.  If someone could provide a clear process for achieving this or a link to such, it'd be most helpful.

I hope I've expressed this clearly, please let me know if you need any further info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I feel like @ffledgling didn't fully answer the question so I am adding a note:

Here is a list of all events sent by the worker to the broker (in your case RabbitMq): http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#event-reference

As you can see, there are few worker self-related messages/events:

- worker-online
- worker-heartbeat
- worker-offline

All of them contain a signature of the hostname. Therefore a successful handshake flow (*not exactly handshake because master doesn't respond with message but using it as a metaphor here*) may look like this:

> >
>   new worker online --> worker send worker-online message to the queue --> master received and start to read logs from worker host --> master schedule tasks --> ...

Beyond that, host name is a standard body field in every event (both task and worker self-related), here is the documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html?highlight=event%20reference#standard-body-fields

For example, if you look at [task-started event](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=event%20reference#task-started): it also contains a hostname as signature, this is how the master knows who picked up the task and where to read the log of the task from.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that Celery is designed for distributed processing. What
>   I have see no docs on at all is, assuming that I have several
>   machines/nodes on the same LAN, how do they discover each other? Does
>   RabbitMQ play a role? Do celery instances somehow discover each other?
>   Is there a list of suitable hosts somewhere? If so, how do I edit it?

Celery is a distributed task queue that works using a message brokering system such as RabbitMQ.

What essentially happens all celery workers connect a shared Queue such as RabbitMQ. The master(s) dispatch work by pushing it onto the queue. Workers who are connected to the Queue as well, pull work off of the queue and then attempt to execute it. Once it is finished (successfully or otherwise), it will push the results back onto the Queue, which the master(s) can then query.

Given this architecture, you do not need to add a list of hosts, they "auto-detect" work. You simply need to start them up and ensure they can talk to the Queue.

A slightly more detailed explanation from another SO answer.

[Link to the architecture with a diagram](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Celery#ARCHITECTURE).

> Also, assuming I'm going to use only one node to handle the HTTP
>   requests, do I still need to have gunicorn running on all nodes? I ask
>   this because in the gunicorn start command, it has a setting for the
>   number of workers. And, is this setting applicable only to that node,
>   or as a max total for all connected nodes?

No, you do not need guicorn running on all the nodes, just the one you're using to serve HTTP requests via python. Celery workers do not need guicorn. The worker setting in guicorn refers to the number of workers in the HTTP listeners pool. This is separate, independent and unrelted to the set of workers that celery uses.

Comment: Hi @ffledgling, thanks for the answer, I know a lot more now than I did before.  I have a couple of clarification questions though.  Where you said: "you do not need to add a list of hosts, they "auto-detect" work. You simply need to start them up and ensure they can talk to the Queue."  HOW do I do this?  It's the basic essence of my original post.  I assume somewhere I tell the celery instances, which file?  Is there a particular format I need to follow?  I did check the link you posted and it's informative, but gives no actual config examples.

Thanks again!